# Questions while using presentModalViewController

Tags: iphone, view

In my application, i tried to use the function 
    [self.navigationCotroller presentModalViewController:nextVC animated:YES];
However, when it goes to the next view, the subview fulfill the whole screen(of course it did)
And the question is , how could i add the bar button which lead the view back?

i have tried to use

1. ```
   self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(Go)];
   ```

   in function viewdidLoad, but it did not work, there's no bar or even button showed
2. ```
   UINavigationBar *bb =  [[UINavigationBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 44)];
   self.NVBar = bb;
   [self.view addSubview:bb];
   ```

However, i have no idea how to add a barbutton to the new navigationBar ---NVBar

Would you like to give me a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pop the new view controller in order for the navigation bar to be automatically included.

In the view controller your code from above is in,

```
//*** Hook up four buttons to these actions and play around with it for a 
//*** better sense of what is going on.    
//*** JSBViewController is the name of my test class
//*** You should use your ViewController class that you are currently coding so
//*** you can see the difference of pop/push versus present/dismiss inside of a            
//*** navigation controller
-(IBAction)push:(id)sender
{
  JSBViewController * viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([JSBViewController class])];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
-(IBAction)pop:(id)sender
{
  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
-(IBAction)present:(id)sender
{
  JSBViewController * viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([JSBViewController class])];
  [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
-(IBAction)dismiss:(id)sender
{
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

For the behavior you are looking for, you will need to use the push method
`[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];`

Answer (score 0):

If you use `[self.navigationController pushViewController:picker animated:YES];` to push your nextVC, then the Nav Bar should stay at the top. Then you can pop back with `    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

It's quite unconventional to use a nav bar to go back from a modal view.
`